# Python BigQuery Error:400 configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Hello everyone what I am trying to do is through a query insert data to a `tableA()`, once data is inserted into `Table A` then delete the newly inserted values in `A`, then write the response/output into `Table B` that I created.

Here is my python code :

```
client = bigquery.Client()
#This is Table B
table_id = "ntest.practice.btabletest"
#here is the table I am writing my deleted output to
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)


sql2 ="""
   INSERT INTO `ntest.practice.atabletest`(%s) VALUES (%s);
   DELETE FROM `ntest.practice.atabletest`
   WHERE name = 'HEART'
"""%(columns_aaa,valueaaa)

query_job1 = client.query(sql2,job_config=job_config)  # Make an API request.
query_job1.result()  # Waits for query to finish
print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
```

Yet, I get an error code saying:

> google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400
>   configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts

Any thoughts on how to fix this error? I don't believe, that my query is wrong, nor my tables or values are incorrect.

Comment: Refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting), you should consider using Data Manipulation Language. Please, take a look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646725/cannot-set-destination-table-with-bigquery-python-api) Stackoverflow thread.

Answer (score 0):

Although BigQuery scripting doesn't support destination table, it doesn't seems that you'll need it for your specific query.

`DELETE` query never writes any data to a destination table. You may work around it by sending `INSERT` first then `DELETE`, this way, destination table will "work" (I mean BigQuery won't complaint about it). But you're getting an empty table.

Comment: I seem to be running into a similar issue, and not quite sure how to resolve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590829/best-way-to-create-randomly-assigned-partitions-in-google-bigquery